# Why do we have an isolated test() inside foo() in Go?

Tags: go

Why is test() function in the following code organized like this, instead of getting everything in the test() out and putting them into foo()? Thanks!

```
func foo() error{
    ...
    err = test() error {
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no way to answer that without context. Code organization is not universal, it's situational.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why you may want a inner function like this, but by far the most common use is when you need to use a local variable from the containing function in the inner function. Why an inner function at all? Sometimes you need it to pass into an library, or you need it for `go` or `defer` statements.

The inner function "closes over" any variables it uses that come from the outer function, and these variables remain valid even after the outer function returns. For this reason functions defined this way are called "closures".

A common use is callbacks and such for use with certain libraries. Sometimes its just easier to make the function you need on the spot.

Another common use is if you want to use `defer` with a block of code. `defer` only works with functions, and often you need variables from the outer function. Generally you see this case used with `recover` and named return values. Obviously this overlaps with reason #1.

Finally sometimes you want to run parts of a function in parallel, so you create a closure and call it in as a goroutine with `go`.

There are of course other uses for closures...